# Drupal 7 print node type

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am trying to print the node type in a tpl but not having much look the code I am using is: type != 'commissions'): ?>

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Try this
$node= node_load($nid); // $nid = your node ID
$type=$node->type;
then check ($type!='commissions')`

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole node object in the tpl file.Perhaps you can:

```
$node->type;
```

Comment: Which tpl file ? node.tpl.php or page.tpl.php @ChrisArcher